# android pictures' dimension ratio

Tags: java, android, decimal

I would like to get the ratio of a picture's height and width and accordingly scaling for it. While i am computing for yratio using

```
float yratio = y_pic / y_original;
```

for y_pic being 800, y_original being 590, I have checked the result for yratio and why yratio would give me 1.0 as the answer?

How could I get an answer of 1.35?? Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the output type is the same as the input types, which is an `integer`.
Use a cast to make it working.

```
float yratio = y_pic / (float) y_original;
```

Comment: oh thanks it works! system need to wait for 10 minutes to accept your answer...thanks a lot!